# Does an upgrade from Ableton Live Standard to Suite cost the same if I already own Max for Live?

Tags: daw, ableton-live

I've already emailed Ableton with this question a couple days ago, but since it's the holidays they haven't answered yet.

I currently own a Live 9 Standard license, and I was thinking about buying Max for Live. However, since I will eventually want to upgrade to a Suite license in the future, will the upgrade price be the same as it would be if I didn't already have Max for Live, or will it take that into account, similarly to how FL Studio upgrades cost less if you already own some of the plugins?

Thanks

Comment: If you hear back from Ableton, I hope you'll post what they say as an answer to your own question. I'm curious about this also.

Comment: Oh I forgot. Licensing questions are off-topic. You might try the Ableton forums and hopefully their support will help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about software licensing are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Ableton emailed back. Here's what they said

> If you buy Max for Live separately, the upgrade price to Suite will still be the same. The "better option" would be to go to Suite directly.